# Bluemix Containers サービス利用で制限等ありますか？

Tags: bluemix

IBM Containers を使用したところ、アプリケーションの（おそらく）ネットワーク接続問題でアプリが高頻度で停止します。

このアプリでは、コンテナで起動しているアプリはslackへ接続するhubotで、slackへのwebsocket通信が一定時間途絶えるとアプリが停止する作りになっています。IBM Containersのグループ機能を使ったり、コンテナ内部でアプリをデーモン化し再起動する運用もためしましたが、いろいろと試行錯誤した10日間で約200回以上の停止がありました。試しに、自宅サーバへコンテナを移動した後には問題なく稼働しています。

IBM Containers上で websocket通信が規制されているなどの制限事項があるのでしょうか？

Comment: ice logsコマンドで、Error Message等、参考となる情報が無いか確認してみていただけますでしょうか？

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_ice.html